# Fitting Vine Copula tree by tree

Tags: r, time-series, copula, vine-copula

I am using the `R` programming language. I want to manually fit the D-vine copula for tree level 2 using `BiCopHfunc().` Still, I got a different result (optimal parameter and copula families) when using `RVineStructureSelect(),` which gives an optimal parameter and copula families output. Could someone please provide the `R` code to fit the 3-dimensional vine copula in tree level 2, where `V` variables as the conditioning variables? My code is:

```
copQV<-BiCop(family = 14, par = 13.37) 
h1<-BiCopHfunc2(pData[,1],pData[,2], copQV)
               
copVD<-BiCop(family = 1, par = 0.77)
h2<-BiCopHfunc1(pData[,2],pData[,3], copVD)

summary(BiCopSelect(h1, h2))
```

Comment: When you use the `RvineStructureSelect,` the function builds the entire R-vine copula model for you. However, you only try to fit specific copula families to the second tree. Hence, of course, you will get a different result. If you want to specify a D-vine copula model with your choice of the bivariate copula families and their parameters, then you should not use the `RvineStructureSelect` function. Instead, you should build your model step by step using the `VineCopula` package.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Anytime. I am happy to help.  :)

Comment: @Dr.Alenezi, please make that as an answer.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods Ok.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the specific type of the copula family in the R-vine copula model,

1. You need to specify the variable structure.
2. Then, you need to build vine matrices for each of the following:

- Variable structure
- Copula family
- parameter for each copula family.

Then, you need to use the `RVineSeqEst()` which will estimate the model parameters sequentially starting from the first tree.

You can fit `RvineStructureSelect` function to select for you the vine copula model. Then, you can extract the matrices for the structure, family and parameters. For example:

```
myfunc <- RVineStructureSelect(your-data)
myfunc$Matrix
myfunc$family
myfunc$par
```

Then, you can modify the copula families as you like and then, re-run your model again using your need families and their parameters.